# Is an AOE resolved like a normal attack, even against larger creatures?

Tags: creature-size, d6-system, area-of-effect

As I didn't find anything. How does AOE work in D6?

I don't mean explosives there but instead some effect like flamethrower or a breath of flames.

Is it like a normal attack? OR are there any rules there at all?
(if it is handled like a normal attack I'm confused about 'size' in regards to this as that would mean that an AOE that is bigger in size than the target has a way harder time hitting it?)

Comment: I'm using the ogl there but star wars D6 answers are also possible (as far as I know the rules are identical there in all regards only that star wars has the size classes a bit more abstractly titled instead of size+3, size+6,...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sadly, neither the OGL or Star Wars (only having Grenades & Mines) provide info here. D6 Fantasy (Check the sidebar of the [OpenD6](http://opend6.wikidot.com/start) for the book) is a better source for an answer, especially the magic section.

- p84 has details about how targeting a spell works (for your desired effect, the use of a skill seems a good fit; in D6 Fantasy this tends to default to **marksmanship**)
- On p91 you have a description of **Area of Effect** (but this is more for fireball like effects)
- **Waterjet** on p98 seems to fit perfectly with what you want to do.

Comment: Cool. can you add a few more details there (a short description)? For ppl who didnt get those books (currently looking into the books to read the things you mentioned up)

Comment: The aoe describes it pretty neatly.  "Compare the targeting roll of spell against the defense total". will have a follow up question there if I'm interpreting a sentence there correctly. but I guess flame breath would work like the area of effect described there.  Thus normal rolls and thus normal effects against large/small targets tnx!

Comment: I know and that is what I usually do although I had doublechecked your answer and it answers the question (only thing I never had read through much was the spells and tere you had found the things ;) )